# Isometries of the symmetric space of $PSL_d(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, symmetric-spaces

Let $G = PSL_d(\mathbb{R})$ and $K = SO(d)$. It is a known fact that the symmetric space $G/K$ can be identified with the space $X_d$ defined by the space of inner products in $\mathbb{R}^d$ up to homothety.

This identification can be done by considering the action of $SL_d(\mathbb{R})$ in $X_d$ given by $$g.o(v, w) = o(g^{-1}v, g^{-1}w)$$
which is transitive and has as its stabilizer conjugates of $SO(n)$.

What I don't understand is how to prove that every isometry of $X_d$ is an element of $PSL_d(\mathbb{R})$.

EDIT: Let $\pi_o(g) = g.o$, with $o \in X_d$. If you compute the derivative of the map $\pi_o$ you get a map $\pi^o: sl_d(\mathbb{R}) \to T_oX_d$ which is an isometry when restricted to the $o$ antisymmetric matrices. You cand then give a Riemannian metric in $X_d$ using this identification and the Killing form in $sl_d(\mathbb{R})$

Comment: What do you mean by "isometry of $X_d$"? That is, what kind of metric is there on $X_d$ to speak of isometries; and also, why should those be in $PSL_d$? I do not understand what exact statement is clear to you and what you want help with. -- Note also that technically, $SO(d)$ is not contained in $PSL_d$, so the quotient $G/K$ needs some interpretation.

Comment: The quotient should be $PSL_d(\mathbb{R})/PSO(d)$, I think (maybe I am mistaken) that this quotient should be the same as $SL_d(\mathbb{R})/SO(d)$, but you are right that $SO(d)$ is not in $PSL_d$. With respect to the metric, I will edit the question to specify it.

Comment: $PSL(d,R)$ is index $2$ in the full isometry group. If you understand the Tits boundary of $X$ you can prove this with the fundamental theorem of projective geometry. I think also Helgason proves this somewhere for irreducible symmetric spaces in general.

Comment: The class of isometries you are missing are the Cartan involutions. Because of these, index is 2, as Max says.